# Reverse Proxy on apache SSL not working and pointing to wrong direction

Tags: apache-virtualhost

I"am running a mailcow server on Debian 11 with reverse proxy on Apache.

I want to have 3 things on this server Mailcow (is running) . Just a normal Webpage. and in the future a nextcloud server to.

My Problem atm is that https://mydomain.com is pointing to my mailcowserver at mail.mydomain.com. But i want that https://mydomain.com redirict to my website.
http://mydomain.com is working properly.

I"am pretty new with this. some help would be nice :).

greetz

nase

Comment: perhaps you configured apache incorrectly, we can't tell

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.